# Get BPMN process's "Normal" Workflow

Tags: bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io

Using Camunda's REST API what would be the best way to get and/or define a workflow's "normal" or "happy path"? I've seen some mention of this in BPMN documentation, but it seems like more of a general 'idea' rather than something specifically supported by the specification. If necessary I can also customize my BPMN workflow to accommodate this normal path notation.

Eventually what I would like is a way to pull a task's process history and display its current path through the workflow along with what the next step in the "normal" case would be. What I'm looking for is just the data (not the diagram) so that I can customize the UI as I see fit.

For now I see I can get the task's history:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/rest/history/user-operation-log/
and the workflow diagram (or XML):
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/rest/process-definition/get-diagram/

Comment: You can query the finished activities (see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/rest/history/activity-instance/get-activity-instance-query/ ) and filter by process instance. Is this what you looking for?

Comment: This is currently what I have running actually, but its only doing half of what I'm looking for. I'd also like a list of what the 'next steps' will be in the "normal" workflow for uncompleted tasks. Obviously there is generally more than one path out, but I'm looking for a way I can specify what the normal case is (ie ignoring exception cases).